# WSO2 ESB Proxy Service Versioning

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any way to create and maintain multiple versions of the same proxy service in WSO2 ESB??.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please track the progress of [this](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-890) JIRA.

Thanks

Thilini